# Silex Doctrine ORM Create Entity

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am trying to connect the doctrine, but I do not quite understand  how I can create entities from the console, so for example, to make it easier to create Many to Many

I have already connected the Doctrine itself:

```
//public/bootstrap/bootstrap.php

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'db.options' => array(// Подробнее настройка DBAL тут: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/doctrine.html
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'dbname' => 'test',
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8'
    )
));
```

there is nothing in the official documentation on how to create entities - https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/providers/doctrine.html

I could not find it on the Internet either, maybe someone knows how to cope with this?